# How to call a Action Name on dropdown change in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to bind data to second dropdownlist on selecting first dropdownlist ?

I have bind first dropdownlist using strongly typed view.

Now how to call action name and bind second dropdownlist on selection first dropdownlist?

```
 <tr>
            <td>Select Make:</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMake, Model.MakesList, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "FillModel()" })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Model</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMake, Model.MakesList)</td>
        </tr>
```

Action Name

```
public ActionResult FillModel(int MakeId)
        {
            var makedata = objVehicleContext.VehicleMakes.Where(m=>m.MakeId==MakeId);

            ViewBag.makelist = makedata.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: You need to use ajax. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247717/how-to-keep-cascade-dropdownlist-selected-items-after-form-submit/33248183#33248183) for an example of creating cascading dropdownlists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Put Jquery function on change of dropdown list. For Example

```
 <tr>


        <td>Select Make:</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMake, Model.MakesList, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "FillModel()", id="ddlMake"

    })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Select Model</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedMake, Model.MakesList,new {@id="ddlModel"})</td>
        </tr>
```

**This Is a simple solution to call the action method on dropdown change.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ddlMake").change(function(){url.action('Controller Name','Action Method Name')})
})
```

**But for further Effects You have to call the Ajax call method and fetch the data. After that on success of the method You have to append the rest of Data On ddlModel. Just Like It.**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#ddlMake").change(function(){
   $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'url.action('Controller Name','Action Method Name')'
        data:{id:$('#ddlMake').val()},
        sucess:{
             $("#ddlModel").append('<option value="' + ModelId.Value + '">' + Model.Text + '</option>');
        }
        });)})
        })
```

**And You need to do this with Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetModel()
    {
        //your dropdown datasource
        return json(ddlModeldatasurce,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correct Then you just need to do simple jquery.post

```
 $("#ddlMake").change(function () {
            $.post("controller/ActionName", function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (val, txt) {
                    $("#ddlModel").append('<option value="' + val + '">' + txt + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
```

> And In controller :

```
    public Actionresult GetModel()
    {
        //your dropdown datasource
        return json(ddlModeldatasurce);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do without using Ajax and JQuery ?

Comment: Yes you can do it by using Viewbag also.But it will cause you a full postback.