# Troubleshooting MVC Cascading Dropdown not populating

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cascadingdropdown

I have two dropdowns in my MVC partial view which is contained under an Area folder in my MVC project. The first dropdown is DB populated and the second one should be populated from a static list contained in a Json controller function.  However I can't seem to get it to populate. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

**Partial View Dropdowns**

```
    <div class="form-group">
    @Html.DropDownList("CommonHerps", new SelectList(Model.CommonHerpNames, 
   "CommonHerpId", "HerpName"), "Select Animal", new {@class = "form-control"})
    </div>
```

**This one should populate based on the select made above**

```
 <div class="form-group">
   @Html.DropDownList("ReptileSpeciesList", new SelectList(string.Empty, 
   "Value", "Text"), "Select Animal", new {@class = "form-control"})
   </div>
```

**Controller Json**

```
 public JsonResult GetGenericSpecies(int cAnimalID)
    {

        List<SelectListItem> genericSpecies = new List<SelectListItem>();
        switch (cAnimalID) 
        {
            case 4:
                    genericSpecies.Add(new SelectListItem { Text= "Burmese Python", Value = "1"});
                    genericSpecies.Add(new SelectListItem { Text= "Reticulated Python", Value = "2"});
                break;
            case 3:
                    genericSpecies.Add(new SelectListItem { Text= "Panther Chameleon", Value = "3"});
                    genericSpecies.Add(new SelectListItem { Text= "Panther Chameleon", Value = "4"});
                break;
        }
        return Json(new SelectList(genericSpecies, "Value", "Text"));

    }//End GetGenericSpecies
```

**JS Script Block**

```
@section Script{

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CommonHerps").change(function () {
                $("#ReptileSpeciesList").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("/GetGenericSpecies")',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: { cAnimalId: $("#CommonHerpId").val() },
                    //Get the value of the common species list and pass it to JSON method as expected property. 

                    success: function (species) {
                        //species contains the list of common species names and the scientific order.

                        $.each(species, function (i, species) {
                            $("#species").append('<option value="' + species.Value + '">' + species.Text + '</option>');
                            //Add option for species. 
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve species.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })

        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Where is `#species`?

Comment: #Species should have been ReptileSpeciesList. I corrected the code in the post.

Comment: You updated code based on @niksofteng comment and are you still sure the updated code not working?

Comment: Where is `#species` that you append options to in `success` callback?

Comment: It needs to be `$("#CommonHerps").change(function () {` - leading hash

Comment: @StephenMuecke `$("CommonHerps").change(function ()` that's already in place.

Comment: Also did you try changing `$("CommonHerps").change(...` to `$("#CommonHerps").change(...` and check the event firing or not? Also change your controller json return function to `return Json(YourListObject, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @niksofteng - the leading `#` (`id` identifier)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You have got sharp eyes. :)

Comment: You might also want to look at the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247717/how-to-keep-cascade-dropdownlist-selected-items-after-form-submit/33248183#33248183) for how to implement the 2nd dropdownlist so that you get correct 2-way binding when editing existing data.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I corrected the missing #

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you. I will check out your answer on that link

Comment: @Alex, Are you saying its still not working? If not, what errors do you get in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not getting showing any error in my console when I run. The 2nd dropdown is still empty

Comment: What does `console.log(species);` in the success callback return (are you getting any data from the controller?)

Comment: And have you corrected the `$("#species").append(..)` to  $(`#ReptileSpeciesList`).append(..)` as noted above

Comment: @StephenMuecke I did correct Species.append() to (#ReptileSpeciesList).append(). console.log(species) comes back with "VM84:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: species is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
(anonymous) @ VM84:1
"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145337/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).