# Related DropDownList's with Ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to do this:

choose an item in the first ddl, and then appears a list of related items in the second ddl. I'm using this method: [How to keep cascade dropdownlist selected items after form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247717/how-to-keep-cascade-dropdownlist-selected-items-after-form-submit)

But I can't handle it and something is wrong(with Ajax I guess) and I have only a list of cities for the first ddl, the second ddl is empty. Please, help.

My view:

```
@model Bike_Store.Models.OrderVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Checkout";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
var url = '@Url.Action("FetchAddresses")';
var adresses = $('#Delivery_id');
$('#Cities_id').change(function () {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
        return;
    }
    $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        adresses.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('-Please select-'));
        $.each(data, function (index, bs_delivery_type) {
            subLocalities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
        });
    });
});
</script>

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Cities_id)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Cities_id, Model.CitiesList, "-Please select-")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Cities_id)

    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Delivery_id)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Delivery_id, Model.DeliveriesList, "-Please Select-")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Delivery_id)
}
```

Model:

```
public class OrderVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address")]
    public decimal? Cities_id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "City")]
    public decimal? Delivery_id { get; set; }
    public SelectList CitiesList { get; set; }
    public SelectList DeliveriesList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
private void ConfigureViewModel(OrderVM model)
{
    IEnumerable<bs_cities> cities = _db.bs_cities;
    model.CitiesList = new SelectList(cities, "cities_id", "cities_name");
    if (model.Cities_id.HasValue)
    {
        IEnumerable<bs_delivery_type> addresses = _db.bs_delivery_type.Where(x => x.delivery_city_id == model.Cities_id.Value);
        model.DeliveriesList = new SelectList(addresses, "delivery_id", "delivery_address");
    }
    else
    {
        model.DeliveriesList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
}

public ViewResult Checkout()
{
    OrderVM model = new OrderVM();
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Checkout(OrderVM model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("123");
    }
}

public JsonResult FetchSubLocalities(int ID)
{
    var bs_delivery_type = _db.bs_cities.Where(x => x.cities_id == ID).Select(c => new
    {
        Value = c.cities_id,
        Name = c.cities_name
    });
    return Json(bs_delivery_type, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? Your ajax is calling a method named `FetchAddresses` but you have not shown that method . (and why are properties `Cities_id` and `Delivery_id` typeof `decimal`?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke browser shows no errors. So I need to rename ajax method in controller to *FetchAdresses*? decimal because in db I have decimal id's.

Comment: ID's as `decimal` make no sense (they should be `int` and auto-incremeted). You need a method named `FetchAddresses` - your current code would be throwing a `404 NotFound` error is you do not have one. And that method needs to return a collection of values associated with `addresses` (e.g `_db.bs_delivery_type.Where(x => x.delivery_city_id == ID).Select(x => new { Value = x.delivery_id, Text = x.delivery_address });` based on the code in the `ConfigureViewModel()` method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but in your example(by the link higher) there were different names in script on View and in Controller, that made me a little confused. So now I renamed `FetchSubLocalities` method to `FetchAddresses` but still cant get items in second ddl. Also changed returning collection.

Comment: Again, you need to check what errors your getting in the browser console (the previous code would have generated a 404 error because you did not have a method named `FetchAddresses`. And you have not shown where your have declared the variable `subLocalities` so it would be undefined. Use your browser tools to debug your scripts (or at least add `console.log(..)` statements to check all your elements are correctly selected and the correct data is returned.

Comment: And I assume `subLocalities.append(..)` is actually supposed to be `address.append(...)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke there was no 404 error. So I guesse script is not working at all. I just copypasted it from your example.

Comment: And your also have `$.each(data, function (index, bs_delivery_type)` but within that function your refer ti `item` - its should be ` `$.each(data, function (index, item) { ... }` or `.val(bs_delivery_type.Value).text(bs_delivery_type.Text))`. I very strongly recommend you learn the basics of debugging your code.

Comment: And since you script is before the html and not wrapped in `$(document)` ready, your referring to elements which do not even exist at that point. Move your scripts to immediately before  the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry, I never practiced in javascript, so it's hard for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145637/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-c-america).