# Cascading dropdown need blank value MVC5

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Hopefully an easy one to answer. I am using the code below to produce a cascading dropdown, however when I select the Country, the State auto populates with the first value (for the appropriate Country) in my State table. I think that I need to add an empty string somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Thanks

```
h2>Cascading DropDownList Sample</h2>



<div>

    <div>

        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownCountry", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a country", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:50px;">


        @Html.DropDownList("dropdownState", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a state", new { @style = "width:250px;" })

    </div>

</div>

@section scripts
{

<script>

    $(function () {

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",

            url: "/test/getcountries",

            datatype: "Json",

            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function (index, value) {

                    $('#dropdownCountry').append('<option value="' + value.CountryId + '">' + value.CountryName +'</option>');

                });

            }

        });



        $('#dropdownCountry').change(function () {



            $('#dropdownState').empty();



            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                url: "/test/GetStatesByCountryId",

                datatype: "Json",

                data: { countryId: $('#dropdownCountry').val() },

                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {

                        $('#dropdownState').append('<option value ="' + value.Id + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>');

                    });

                }

            });

        });

    });

</script>
    }
```

Comment: Suggest you refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247717/how-to-keep-cascade-dropdownlist-selected-items-after-form-submit/33248183#33248183) for the correct way to handle cascading dropdownlists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your country drop down change event success call back function you have to make one line of change.

```
$('#dropdownState').append('<option>Select State</option>');
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
     $('#dropdownState').append('<option value ="' +
         value.Id + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>');
 });
```

And I suggest you put your options in variable and finally assign that value to drop down.

```
var html = '';
html = '<option>Select State</option>';
$.each(data, function (index, value) {
     html += '<option value ="' +
         value.Id + '">' + value.StateName + '</option>';
 });
$('#dropdownState').html(html)
```

append function add options to select element  which will cause problem like if you select country A which will provide 5 states. Then you select country B which provides 10 states then final result in states drop down will be 15 states option for country B. Thus instead of append I have used html function.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a mock item in the first place of the elements returned by the service GetStatesByCountryId. The id field can be blank and the statename can be something like "Please Choose". Then, you can check if the selected item id is blank or not.