# Edit Cascade DropDownList using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble retrieving/displaying the CityId value from the database to the City drop down list based on the selected Customer's ID that I wish to Edit.

When I select a Customer to Edit it populates the data from the database properly except for the City drop down list. The City drop down list will show "Select a City" along with all Cities that are related to the State in the State drop down list.

If I select another state then it loads all cities for the selected state properly.

The problem is that it does not show the City value for the City drop down list like it should when I first load the page based on the selected Customer ID.

I'm very new to jQuery/AJAX and I had someone help me with the jQuery code for the cascade drop down lists.

I supplied my ViewModel, Controller and Edit View that I'm using now below:

**Customer Model**

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }

    public int LocalityId { get; set; }
    public Locality Locality { get; set; }

    public int SubLocalityId { get; set; }
    public SubLocality SubLocality { get; set; }
}
```

**City Model**

```
public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<Locality> Localities { get; set; }
}
```

**Locality Model**

```
public class Locality
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<SubLocality> SubLocalities { get; set; }
}
```

**SubLocality Model**

```
public class SubLocality
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int LocalityId { get; set; }
    public Locality Locality { get; set; }

    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

**WebAppDbContext**

```
public class WebAppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public WebAppDbContext(DbContextOptions<WebAppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Locality> Localities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubLocality> SubLocalities { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(c => c.CustomerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.FirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property(c => c.LastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasKey(ci => ci.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .Property(ci => ci.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasMany(ci => ci.Customers)
            .WithOne(c => c.City)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CityId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
            .HasMany(l => l.Localities)
            .WithOne(ci => ci.City)
            .HasForeignKey(ci => ci.CityId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Locality>()
            .HasKey(l => l.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Locality>()
            .Property(l => l.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Locality>()
            .HasMany(l => l.Customers)
            .WithOne(c => c.Locality)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.LocalityId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Locality>()
            .HasMany(sl => sl.SubLocalities)
            .WithOne(l => l.Locality)
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.LocalityId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubLocality>()
            .HasKey(sl => sl.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubLocality>()
            .Property(sl => sl.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<SubLocality>()
            .HasMany(sl => sl.Customers)
            .WithOne(c => c.SubLocality)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.SubLocalityId);
    }
}
```

**CustomerFormVM**

```
public class CustomerFormVM
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a First Name")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Last Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a city")]
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public int? SelectedCity { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a locality")]

    [Display(Name = "Locality")]
    public int? SelectedLocality { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a sub locality")]
    [Display(Name = "Sub Locality")]
    public int? SelectedSubLocality { get; set; }

    public SelectList CityList { get; set; }
    public SelectList LocalityList { get; set; }
    public SelectList SubLocalityList { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomersController**

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    private readonly WebAppDbContext _context;

    public CustomersController(WebAppDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }


    // GET: Customers
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var webAppDbContext = _context.Customers.Include(c => c.City).Include(c => c.Locality).Include(c => c.SubLocality);
        return View(await webAppDbContext.ToListAsync());
    }


    // GET: Customers/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var customer = await _context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.City)
            .Include(c => c.Locality)
            .Include(c => c.SubLocality)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CustomerId == id);

        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(customer);
    }


    // GET: Customers/Create
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        CustomerFormVM model = new CustomerFormVM();
        ConfigureViewModel(model);
        return View(model);
    }


    // POST: Customers/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CustomerFormVM vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var customer = new Customer();
            {
                customer.FirstName = vm.FirstName;
                customer.LastName = vm.LastName;
                customer.CityId = vm.SelectedCity.Value;
                customer.LocalityId = vm.SelectedLocality.Value;
                customer.SubLocalityId = vm.SelectedSubLocality.Value;
            }
            _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        else
        {
            ConfigureViewModel(vm);
            return View(vm);
        }
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FetchLocalities(int ID)
    {
        var data = _context.Localities
            .Where(l => l.CityId == ID)
            .Select(l => new { val = l.ID, text = l.Name });
        return Json(data);
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult FetchSubLocalities(int ID)
    {
        var data = _context.SubLocalities
            .Where(l => l.LocalityId == ID)
            .Select(l => new { val = l.ID, text = l.Name });
        return Json(data);
    }


    private void ConfigureViewModel(CustomerFormVM model)
    {
        List<City> cities = _context.Cities.ToList();
        model.CityList = new SelectList(cities, "ID", "Name");
        if (model.SelectedCity.HasValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<Locality> localities = _context.Localities.Where(l => l.CityId == model.SelectedCity.Value);
            model.LocalityList = new SelectList(localities, "ID", "Name");
        }
        else
        {
            model.LocalityList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
        }
        if (model.SelectedLocality.HasValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<SubLocality> subLocalities = _context.SubLocalities.Where(l => l.LocalityId == model.SelectedLocality.Value);
            model.SubLocalityList = new SelectList(subLocalities, "ID", "Name");
        }
        else
        {
            model.SubLocalityList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
        }
    }


    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var customervm = new CustomerFormVM();
        {
            Customer customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == id);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            customervm.CustomerId = customer.CustomerId;
            customervm.FirstName = customer.FirstName;
            customervm.LastName = customer.LastName;
        }
        return View(customervm);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(CustomerFormVM vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Customer customer = _context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CustomerId == vmEdit.CustomerId);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            customer.FirstName = vmEdit.FirstName;
            customer.LastName = vmEdit.LastName;

            _context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(vmEdit);
    }


    // GET: Customers/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var customer = await _context.Customers
            .Include(c => c.City)
            .Include(c => c.Locality)
            .Include(c => c.SubLocality)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CustomerId == id);
        if (customer == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(customer);
    }


    // POST: Customers/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var customer = await _context.Customers.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CustomerId == id);
        _context.Customers.Remove(customer);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    private bool CustomerExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Customers.Any(e => e.CustomerId == id);
    }
}
```

**Create View**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Customers"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCity)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCity, Model.CityList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCity)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLocality)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocality, Model.LocalityList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLocality)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSubLocality)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubLocality, Model.SubLocalityList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubLocality)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}


<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
   var localityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchLocalities")';
   var subLocalityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchSubLocalities")';
            var localities = $('#SelectedLocality');
            var subLocalities = $('#SelectedSubLocality');
            $('#SelectedCity').change(function() {
    localities.empty();
    subLocalities.empty();
    $.getJSON(localityUrl, { ID: $(this).val() },function (data) {
     if (!data) {
      return;
     }
     localities.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
     $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      localities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.val).text(item.text));
     });
    });
   })
            $('#SelectedLocality').change(function() {
    subLocalities.empty();
                $.getJSON(subLocalityUrl, { ID: $(this).val() },function (data) {
     if (!data) {
      return;
     }
                    subLocalities.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please Select'));
     $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      subLocalities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.val).text(item.text));
     });
    });
   })

</script>

}
```

**Edit View**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Customers"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(c => c.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedCity)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCity, Model.CityList, "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCity)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedLocality)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocality, Model.LocalityList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedLocality)
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSubLocality)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubLocality, Model.SubLocalityList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedSubLocality)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CustomerId)

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

<script type="text/javascript">
   var localityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchLocalities")';
   var subLocalityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchSubLocalities")';
            var localities = $('#SelectedLocality');
            var subLocalities = $('#SelectedSubLocality');
            $('#SelectedCity').change(function() {
    localities.empty();
    subLocalities.empty();
    $.getJSON(localityUrl, { ID: $(this).val() },function (data) {
     if (!data) {
      return;
     }
     localities.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
     $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      localities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.val).text(item.text));
     });
    });
   })
            $('#SelectedLocality').change(function() {
    subLocalities.empty();
                $.getJSON(subLocalityUrl, { ID: $(this).val() },function (data) {
     if (!data) {
      return;
     }
                    subLocalities.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please Select'));
     $.each(data, function(index, item) {
      subLocalities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.val).text(item.text));
     });
    });
   })

</script>

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that JQUERY is working? In the view I put inside section script   this markup <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> (change correct version).

Comment: Yes, the jQuery code is working on my end. jQuery 2.2.0

Comment: I have the same jQuery code for my Create Method which works fine, the only problem I'm having is that I cannot retrieve the CityId based on the selected CustomerId for the Edit Method.

Comment: Why do you need this ` $("#StateId").trigger('change');` ? Your page will load the selected city in the dropdown with the server code you have.

Comment: @Shyju, to be 100% honest with you, I'm not very knowledgeable with jQuery or Ajax. Someone provided that to me to use for the Create Method which works fine. The Edit Method is what I'm having trouble with. As of now, when I load the page for Edit it displays the correct "state" value in the dropdownlist which then populates the correct "cities" for the cities drop down list. The problem is that I need the city drop down list to display the value from the database along with the cities that are related to the state that gets loaded.

Comment: just comment out that line and see what happens

Comment: I commented out that line of code and now it populates the correct city value for the city drop down list. However, when I click on the city drop down list it shows me all cities for every state instead of showing the cities that are just related to the particular state.

Comment: Suggest you refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247717/how-to-keep-cascade-dropdownlist-selected-items-after-form-submit/33248183#33248183) for how to handle this correctly

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, thank you for the post, I did look at that link but it has to do with Creating, I'm having trouble with Editing. The link to that Post is also broken. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong or not doing with my posted code?

Comment: Read it again. Its for both, and is the correct way to handle this to make everything work correctly including 2-way binding, client side validation etc which your code will not do!

Comment: I have updated the link in that answer.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, it does seem like a better solution than what I'm trying to accomplish now. Would it be possible if you could assist me in how I should modify my code to make this work? If not, I can try myself and get back to this post later after I try.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke, I tried to implement my code with what the other user was trying to do. So far I'm getting an error on this method **ConfigureViewModel** on this line `_context.States.Where(c => c.StateId == model.StateId.Value);` **Error Message** is _Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TwoCascadeDropDownList.Models.State>'to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TwoCascadeDropDownLists.Models.City>'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)_

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have not yet, tried the .NET Fiddle solution you posted since I'm not sure if that will work with ASP.NET Core MVC. Also, I wasn't sure if I was permitted to update my code from my original post to what I have now.

Comment: If you do not update the code, then it will not work :) - and it will work fine with asp.net-core-mvc (but that is not what you have tagged your question with). And the other answer your referring to is mine and it works but I have no idea what code your using - you have not shown it!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I updated my Code above. I included my Models, ViewModels, Controller and Create View. I'm able to run the Create View now and it retrieves a list of my States. However, when I select a State value in the drop down list it does not populate any cities.

Comment: Use the code in the question I linked to (or the DotNetFiddle) - it works fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I modified my code to mimic the same code that you supplied in the other question. I have not yet  tried the DotNetFiddle code because that code uses three drop down lists to whereas I have two drop down lists.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I created a project based on the DotNetFiddle project that you created and so far I"m having some trouble. For starters I get the name 'JsonRequestBehavior' does not exist in the current context. It appears that JsonRequestBehavior has been deprecated in ASP.NET Core 1.0. Then, if I correct that issue the page loads and I can select a city but the localities only populate 2 empty string values. I have not even attempted to populate the values from my database. I'm strictly going off your project from DotNetFiddle.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have tried a second time as well just to make sure I didn't have any typo's and I cannot get it to work based on the link you supplied. It only retrieves the City values in the dropdown list and then it populates "please select" for Locality that displays 2 empty fields and then the Sub Locality drop down is populates with "please select' with no value(s). I hate asking for help unless I'm really stuck and I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I finally figured it out, it was the jQuery code that I had to modify. So far, I have been able to retrieve the values from my database instead of the values from the Repository and I'm able to successfully submit the values in my Create Method. However, going back to my original question, I'm having trouble with the Edit Method. Can you please assist me with this last part? Please see my updated code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, all good now. I got the Edit Get and Post to work. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missing this directive on the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

Comment: I replaced what I had with what  you supplied but I got the same result.