# how to fill dropdownlistfor after post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have

```
<form>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.City, provinces, "--Select City--", new { @class = "dropdownList" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.district, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "--Select district--")
    <input type="submit" id="submitRegister" value="submit" />
</form>
```

after post I take modalstate error and then I missing district. how I can set district after error post

Comment: This is appears to be cascading dropdowns (and you have not shown any of the code relevant to that), but I suggest you refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247717/how-to-keep-cascade-dropdownlist-selected-items-after-form-submit/33248183#33248183)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood and solved the problem.
I updated controller

```
 return View(model)
```

I then refilled the list this way.

```
@{ if (Model != null)
var _id = Convert.ToInt32(Model.City);
var DistrictService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService();
var district= DistrictService.Search( x => x.ProvinceId == _id).ToList();
List _district = new List();
foreach (var item in district)
{
 _district.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.Id.ToString(), Text = item.Name});
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.district, _district, new { @class = "dropdownList"});

else {
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.district, Enumerable.Empty< SelectListItem >(), "--Select--", new { @class = "dropdownList", disabled = true });
}
```