# ASP.NET MVC Cascade ComboBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to refresh my ComboBox based on the choices of the ComboBox above.
I have the following code for the controller :

**Controller method code to fill the second Combobox based on the choice of the first**

```
public JsonResult Testeeee(int id_cat )
{
    var result = new dificuldade();

    SqlCommand com;

    string str;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=DESKTOP-4GPISBO\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Jogo;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    conn.Open();

    str = "select tipo_dificuldade, dificuldade.id_dificuldade " +
           "from dificuldade " +
           "INNER JOIN palavra ON palavra.id_dificuldade = dificuldade.id_dificuldade " +
           "where palavra.id_cat = '" + id_cat + "'  ";

    com = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        result.TIPO_DIFICULDADE = reader["tipo_dificuldade"].ToString();
        result.id_dificuldade = int.Parse(reader["id_dificuldade"].ToString());

    }
    conn.Close();

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This is my view code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id_cat, ViewBag.ListaCategoria as SelectList, "-- Selecione a Categoria --", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.id_dificuldade, new SelectList(" "),  "-- Selecione a Dificuldade --",  new { @class = "form-control"  })
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id_cat").change(function () {
        $.get("/Home/Testeeee", { id_cat: $("#id_cat").val() }, function (data) {
            $("#id_dificuldade").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                $("#id_dificuldade").append("<option value='" + row.id_dificuldade + "'>" + row.TIPO_DIFICULDADE + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
```

**My problem**

My problem is that the value returns `undefined` in the second ComboBox, as if the value wasn't returning or not being recognized.

Comment: Your controller method returns a single `dificuldade`, not a collection (and you cannot iterate a single object)

Comment: How can I make it return as a list ?

Comment: Initialize a `List<dificuldade>` and use `while (reader.Read())` to add new instances of `dificuldade` to that collection, and then return the collection

Comment: Can you make an example with my controller ? If you can, I'm kinda of new to MVC. Thanks ! ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Testeeee()` method is returning a single instance of a `dificuldade`, not a collection. Change the method to create a collection and add each when reading the data

```
public JsonResult Testeeee(int id_cat )
{
    List<dificuldade> model = new List<dificuldade>();
    ....
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        dificuldade item = new dificuldade();
        item.TIPO_DIFICULDADE = reader["tipo_dificuldade"].ToString();
        item.id_dificuldade = int.Parse(reader["id_dificuldade"].ToString());
        model.Add(item);
    }
    conn.Close();
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As a side note, you have other issues including that you will loose data if you need to return the view in the POST method, and your code will not display the correct data if editing existing records. Refer [How to keep cascade dropdownlist selected items after form submit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247717/how-to-keep-cascade-dropdownlist-selected-items-after-form-submit/33248183#33248183)

Comment: IT WORKS ! THANK YOU SO MUCH, I NOW UNDERSTAND WHY IT DIDN'T WORK !!

Comment: Please don't yell at us :)